# Why doesn't c# wait for python code to finish?

Tags: c#, python

I can run my code from cmd however the c# code doesn't wait for python to finish it's just closing the window.

I have tried ironpython, but that gives me error for unknown libraries that I'm importing in python.

```
string result = string.Empty;
try
{
    var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = @"D:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python36\python.exe";
    info.Arguments = @"D:\detect.py" + " " + "--images img";

    info.RedirectStandardInput = false;
    info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    info.CreateNoWindow = false;
    using (var proc = new Process())
    {
        proc.StartInfo = info;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        if (proc.ExitCode == 0)
        {
            result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    richTextBox1.Text += result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Script failed: " + result, ex);
}
```

Python code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2


print("a")

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", required=True, help="path to images         directory")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# initialize the HOG descriptor/person detector
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())

# loop over the image paths
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(args["images"]))
print("b")
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # load the image and resize it to (1) reduce detection time
    # and (2) improve detection accuracy
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = imutils.resize(image, width=min(400, image.shape[1]))
    orig = image.copy()

    print('c')
```

...There is more code here but it the window is already closed by that time.

"a" and "b" appears in the result, however "c" never does, I need to give arguments from C# to python and get some result values back, any ideas?

Comment: uhm, could you output/`print` how many entries the `imagePaths` list has? Also do a `print('d')` after the `for` loop.

Comment: `proc.WaitForExit();` waits for Python to finish. The assumption underlying your question is wrong. Thing is, your Python script just finished extremly quickly. Probably do to some error during the execution of the script there...

Comment: Not from c# the for doesn't run, also nothing after the for loop either so no print('d') after for

Comment: I notice you provide a relative image path there in your command line for the script, which could make your script go kaboom if the current working directory is not the "_correct_" directory. Using relative paths while being unaware of the current working directory (or blindly assuming the current working directory will be "_just right_") is a common "_trap for young players_".

Comment: @elgonzo I tried different python scripts(one should be running really long) everytime it stops at the for loop, simple python scripts runs no problem. Maybe there are some errors but I'm not getting any in the output and if I deliberately make an error that shows up there.

Comment: I also tried with a full path + @"--images D:\img"; same result

Comment: Well, then redirect the standard error stream like you did for the standard output stream and see if some error message has been written to the error channel.

Comment: StreamReader myStreamReader = proc.StandardError;                   MessageBox.Show(myStreamReader.ReadToEnd()); Is empty, however code after for i in range(5, 8):  runs, so I guess there is a problem accessing/reading the images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with accessing the image folder from python side, I managed to solve by placing both the python file and the image folder inside bin/Debug/
Then the above c# code will work, however not in everycase one python file started and never finished, the following c# code solved that problem:

```
     System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
          process.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
          {
              UseShellExecute = false,
              CreateNoWindow = false,
              WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
              FileName = "cmd.exe",
              Arguments = @"/C python detect_slow.py --images img", 
              RedirectStandardError = true,
              RedirectStandardOutput = true
          };
          process.Start();
          string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
          process.WaitForExit();

          richTextBox1.Text += output;
```